# Can't upload file to a server using curl

Tags: file-upload, curl

I'm trying to upload a file to a server using curl. It should be uploaded a binary file regardless the format it is in. But I'm having an error:

```
 curl -d @/home/alex/123.log localhost:9000/myupload/
```

The error (the warning, actually) is

```
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "123.log", this makes an empty POST.
```

P.S. Shouldn't I use `--data-binary` instead of `-d`? I didn't find any documentation for `--data-binary`.

Comment: It could be either a permission problem (your user has no read permission over this file) or simply that the file does not exist (a typo in the path?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from [Curl's document](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d):

*-d, --data is the same as --data-ascii. To post data **purely binary**, you should instead use the --data-binary option. To URL-encode the value of a form field you may use --data-urlencode.*

More about the [--data-binary](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary) parameter.

Note: Make sure you have permission to access the file that you wanted to upload to the sever.